# centre of a non-abelian 2-dimensional Lie algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

I stumbled across this statement and I have trouble solving it.

Let L be a non-abelian 2-dimensional Lie algebra. Then the centre of L is trivial, meaning 
Z(L)=0.

How can one solve this?

Comment: It follows from your [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3617344/up-to-isomorphism-there-is-a-unique-2-dimensional-non-abelian-lie-algebra) because we may assume $[x,y]=x$ for the Lie bracket. Hence the center is trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's non-Abelian then it's spanned by two elements $a$ and $b$ with $[a,b]\ne0$.
Can you show that for any non-zero $c\in L$ that either $[a,c]\ne0$ or $[b,c]\ne0$?

Comment: yes, it works! thanks so much